# Python tkniter como generar pestañas para tener simultaneamente dos editores

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy creando un programa que es un editor de texto, pero a este quiero incorporarle pestañas (como en Google o como en Visual Studio), estuve buscando y no encontre nada relacionado con el tema, y me gustaría saber si existe algo específico para crearlas o es algo más complicado.

Comment: te refieres a esto? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-tabbed-widget-with-python-tkinter/

Comment: Adicional, hay [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459376/12913664) en el sitio en inglés que añade el botón de cerrar a la pestaña.

Comment: Como dice @LucasBois se hace con `ttk.Notebook`

Comment: @LucasBois muchas gracias, si esto era lo que buscaba